# Printing flowdocument adds border to table

Tags: wpf, xaml, pdf, printing, flowdocument

I am building flowdocument from ViewModel and then print it to pdf.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication5.View.TransferTemplate" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5.Properties" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5.ViewModels" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:WarehouseActionViewModel}" mc:Ignorable="d"
  x:Name="templ">
  <FlowDocument FontFamily="Cambria" FontSize="14" Background="White" x:Name="doc" d:ColumnWidth="1024">

    <Paragraph>
      <Run>Date: </Run>
      <Run Text="{Binding Action.ActionDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" />
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run>Note: </Run>
      <Run Text="{Binding Action.Note}" />
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run>Sender: </Run>
      <Run Text="{Binding Action.WarehouseFrom}" />
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run>Receiver: </Run>
      <Run Text="{Binding Action.WarehouseTo}" />
    </Paragraph>

    <Table x:Name="border" CellSpacing="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource WhiteBg}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WhiteBg}">
      <Table.Columns>
        <TableColumn Width="0.2*" />
        <TableColumn Width="0.7*" />
        <TableColumn Width="0.1*" />
      </Table.Columns>

      <TableRowGroup>
        <TableRow FontSize="16">
          <TableCell BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" Padding="5">
            <Paragraph>
              <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.barcode}" d:Text="Code" />
            </Paragraph>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" Padding="5">
            <Paragraph>
              <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" d:Text="Name" />
            </Paragraph>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" Padding="5">
            <Paragraph>
              <Run Text="{x:Static p:Resources.quantity}" d:Text="Quantity" />
            </Paragraph>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow/>
      </TableRowGroup>
    </Table>
  </FlowDocument>
</UserControl>



PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        FlowDocument f = new TransferTemplate(vm).doc;
        f.ColumnWidth = printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth;
        IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = f;
        if ((bool)printDlg.ShowDialog())
        {
            printDlg.PrintDocument(dps.DocumentPaginator, "flow doc");
        }
```

The problem is when I create it from template and print it adds black border to table
**(border thickness is set to 0)**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

but when I create document without xaml template with same code in c# it does not add border
**(border thickness not set)**

```
var table1 = new Table
        {
            CellSpacing = 0,
            Background = Brushes.White
        };
        flowDoc.Blocks.Add(table1);
enter code here
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How can I fix XAML template to disable border?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlYhX.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoZnF.png

Comment: try to set the BorderBrush to null too , may be it'll work !!!

Comment: @Romylussone , thanks, but did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just removed `x:Name` from the table and it worked!

**Tip**: Adding the `Name` property to any of the Flowdocument block elements adds a black border when printing (I only tested printing to PDF).

Answer (score 1):

If `Name` is required, then you can replace it with `Tag`.

```
TableCell Tag="Purpose2"  MouseLeftButtonDown="Purpose_Click"
```

The sender is `TableCell` `tb`

```
MessageBox.Show(tb.Tag.ToString()
```